# How to create a VxWorks Layer with subprojects that compile to binaries?

Tags: vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I have multiple RTPs under different projects within the same workspace that I would like to compile and include their binaries through the use of VxWorks binary layers. Like so:

- sub_project1

  - main.c
- sub_project2

  - main.c
- sub_project3

  - main.c
- sub_project4

  - main.c
    layer.vsbl

Each subproject compiles into its own .vxe file and can be included individually in the VIP

I have tried reading the documentation and adding the required subprojects as project references within the layer, however I want to be able to include the binaries as needed through the use of the vsbl